# About making game development account for publishing Android-related games?

Tags: unity, android, google-play, steam

Registering as Google Play Developer requires a fee in order to publish games that have been invested in exchange for money. What about Steam? Is it required the same thing in registration or not?

Also, is it possible to publish Android games on Steam? If yes, how? My main game engine is Unity. Nothing else...and I'm gonna use it for making games before publishing. I have to check for possibilities before a quick conclusion that only Unreal engine is allowed to make games and published on Steam.

Comment: You can easily find out if Google Play Developer publishing requires a fee by simply searching for "Steam publish cost" or "Google play publish cost". You can also easily find out whether Unity can export a Windows or Linux version of your games. This shouldn't even take fifteen minutes to find out, I'm voting this down for lack of research.

Comment: I'm not sure why is this question related to Unity or UE4? Could you focus on a single question?

Comment: @JohnHamilton *Steam* publish fee around $100

Comment: @DavidDimalanta I know that. I have done the same search I've suggested you to do. It's not rocket science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steam is a lot more strict, than something like the play store. You either need a publisher, who has a contract with Valve or you need to submit you game to Steam Direct, which costs you $500 dollars, but you can get it back later if the game gets accepted.

And no, you can't publish android games on Steam, it's a PC game marketplace. Even if you could, the fee is much higher. You can either publish it on the play store or port it to PC.